# Logstash : process special log format

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Is there any Logstash filter available to process this king of log/s

input log for mat -

```
apple=1 | banana= 3 | mango=5
```

or

```
apple=1 | banana= 3 | mango=5 | tiger=7 | elepnat=1
```

output of filter will be as follows -

```
{
    "apple": "1"
    "banana": "3"
    "banana": "5"
}
```

or

```
{
    "apple": "1"
    "banana": "3"
    "banana": "5"
    "tiger": "7"
    "elepnat": "1"
}
```

**Note:** Number of keys & values in input log may vary randomly, ex. in 1st log there are 3, in last log there are 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `kv` Logstash filter. Simply add this filter to your configuration:

```
filter {
   ...
   kv {
      source => "your_field"
      field_split => "|"
      value_split => "="
      trim_key => "\s"
      trim_value => "\s"
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val,
Can you please check this one?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489847/logstash-is-not-reading-from-kafka