# Logstash is not reading from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I am testing a simple pipeline - 
Filebeat > Fafka > Logstash > File.

Logstash is not reading from Kafka, but I see Kafka has messages when i use this command -

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic MyTopic --from-beginning
```

My file beat configuration -

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /root/LogData/input.log

output.kafka:
  hosts: ["10.247.186.14:9092"]

  topic: MyTopic 
  partition.round_robin:
    reachable_only: false

  required_acks: 1
  compression: none
  max_message_bytes: 1000000
```

My Logstash configuration

```
input {
        kafka {
                bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
                topics => ["MyTopic"]
        }

}

output {

        file {
                path => "/usr/share/logstash/test_out.log"

        }
}
```

My Fafka & Logstash are running on same VM, 
I am using Logstash docker, I started the docker of Logstash as follows -

```
sudo docker run -d --name logstash --expose 25826 -p 25826:25826 docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.4.0 --debug
```

Filebeat running on different VM.

I am creating topic as follows -

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic MyTopic
```

Comment: Could you assign a group_id to your consumer and check the consumer status/offset using kafka command line tools? Also your logstash logs would be helpful in better understanding the problem.

Comment: Thanks for response, on my file logstash logs, i am getting this - 
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path //usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs to console
09:33:22.209 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5,

Comment: "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125}
09:33:22.220 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Pipeline main started
09:33:22.346 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.